# In Codeigniter 4, how to display database name and table prefix?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

So far in codeigniter 3 we can get database name and table prefix *(as mentioned in `config/database.php`)* from the below code lines:

```
echo $this->db->database;
echo $this->db->dbprefix('emp_table');
```

Now how can we call these values in Codeigniter 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in Codeigniter 4.0.1 this is what you are looking for

```php
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
$Database = $db->database();
$DBPrefix = $db->getPrefix();
```

I hope this work for you

Comment: One more issue I'm facing. How can I use `$db = \Config\Database::connect();` globally in controller as well as in models?

Comment: @RohitGusain there is no need for $db = \Config\Database::connect(); in your model because the model is already connected with the db. I think this ci4 document will help you more to solve this issue codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/models/model.html then in controller ``$this->db = \Config\Database::connect();`` in baseController iniController method then extends other controllers to it. This is if you do not wish to use model in your controller

Answer (score 1):

There are some changes in  CI4, Inside controller's constructor,

write:

```
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
define('production',$db->database);
```

Comment: This works fine for production global variable in CI4

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db->database` This will work. its Access Modifiers is `protected`. So this property can be accessed within the class and by classes derived from that class. So to get globally use a `public` function as

```
public function get_db_name(){
   return $this->db->database;
}
```